# Azure Search and Linq for Exact Phrase

Tags: content-search, azure-search

We are using Azure Search engine (I know...) and need to so a search for an exact phrase. Using the PredicateBuilder, if I have a statement like:
**keyword = "Mary Smith";**
**predicate = predicate.Or(x => x.Body.Equals(keyword))**

the resulting search query in Azure Search is more like
**&search=(body:(Mary Smith))**

That returns records with Rosemary, Maryland, Smithfield, Blacksmith etc.

I know that if I feed the Azure Search engine the query
**&search=(body("Mary Smith"))**

it will return only records with **Mary Smith**

Passing a query such as
**predicate = predicate.Or(x => x.Body.Equals("\"Mary Smith\""))**

does not yield the desired Azure query [it yields **&search=(body(\"Mary Smith\"))**] which also returns the same as the first query.

Can I get the desired Azure Search query using Linq?  Should I bypass the query mapper and generate the Azure search query directly, then pass the resulting query string to some lower level method in Sitecore to perform the search?

Comment: did you try `.Contains` or `.like`?

Comment: Thanks for ideas, but none of those generate the right query.  Since this is a search for a name, using AND does not do it.  Contains generates /.*Mary.*/ /.*Smith.*/